# JAVA - How to replace tokens in a string

Tags: java

I have a string like:

```
String message = "Hello {0}, the max amount is {1}, {2} ..." ;
```

Where message to replace {0}, {1}, {2} is in a String array :

```
String[] strings = new String[1];
strings[0] = object.CONSTANTE;
strings[1] = object.CONSTANTE1;
strings[2] = object.CONSTANTE2;
```

And i want an exception when the number of arguments in the array isn't the same than in the message.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use [String#format](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) ?

Comment: What about `MessageFormat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this.

String message = "Hello {0}, the max amount is {1}, {2} ..." ;
Where message to replace {0}, {1}, {2} is in a String array :

```
String[] strings = new String[3];
strings[0] = object.CONSTANTE;
strings[1] = object.CONSTANTE1;
strings[2] = object.CONSTANTE2;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        message = message.replace("{"+i+"}", strings[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The [MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class as part for the JDK does exactly what you want.

```
String message   = "Hello {0}, the max amount is {1}, {2} ..." ;
String formatted = MessageFormat.format(message, string1, string2, string3);
```

Answer (score 4):

[`java.text.MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) is exactly what you want.

The class has a static method [format that can be called using a message and an `Object[]`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) (varargs are arrays).

You could do it like that:

```java
String message = "Hello {0}, the max amount is {1}, {2} ...";
String[] strings = { object.CONSTANTE, object.CONSTANTE1, object.CONSTANTE2 };
String formatted = MessageFormat.format(message, strings);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Or, even shorter:

```java
String formatted = MessageFormat.format("Hello {0}, the max amount is {1}, {2} ...",
    object.CONSTANTE, object.CONSTANTE1, object.CONSTANTE2);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java provides the Formatter class for performing substitutions inside a string.

**Here is an example program for substituting values inside a string, as per the above requirement:**

```
// File name:  Demo.java

import java.util.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] constants = new String[3];
        constants[0] = "CONSTANTE";
        constants[1] = "CONSTANTE1";
        constants[2] = "CONSTANTE2";

        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter(message);
        formatter.format("Hello {%s}, the max amount is {%s}, {%s}", 
                          constants[0], constants[1], constants[2]);
        System.out.println(message.toString());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
> javac Demo.java
> java Demo

Hello {CONSTANTE}, the max amount is {CONSTANTE1}, {CONSTANTE2}
```